# Is it possible to replace mail() with PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Is it possible to replace default mail() function with PHPMailer so that all the scripts use Phpmailer, just like using msmtp for gmail instead of changing all the code.

Answer (score 0):

No. PHPMailer *uses* the mail function, but it does a lot more than mail does, so it can't act as a compatible drop-in replacement.

Comment: PHPMailer supports multiple transports internally, including `mail()` and SMTP

Comment: That’s not what was asked, nor what I said. Perhaps you should check out who the maintainer of PHPMailer is to see if they might be correct.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for making PHPMailer. Whether you meant "no" you can't override functions in PHP (there are ways) or more specifically what you said (that PHPMailer has an internal dependency on `mail()` resulting in a circular dependency, which is only true if you don't choose another transport) I think the answer is still wrong.

Comment: By "no" I mean that there is nothing you can do to the built-in mail() function to make it send using PHPMailer instead. You could do many other things to send mail using PHPMailer, but not the thing that was explicitly asked for. The only workaround I can think of would be to install an error handler, deliberately configure php.ini to throw errors from mail(), then send using PHPMailer in the error handler instead. This is conjecture, as I'm not sure you can get everything from the original context in the error handler (e.g. full params).